# Extending the Domain, by interchanging the order of limits.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be continuous on an open set $D$ and of class $C^{(1)}$ on $D \setminus \{x_0\}$.

f is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

$\displaystyle l_i= \lim_{\mathbf{x}\longrightarrow \mathbf{x}_0}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x})$ exists for each $i=1,\ldots,n$.

I want to prove that $l_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x}_0)$ .

$\displaystyle l_i=\lim_{\textbf{x}\longrightarrow \textbf{x}_0} \lim_{t\longrightarrow 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x}+t\textbf{e}_i)-f(\textbf{x})}{t}$

Since $l_i$ exists

$\displaystyle l_i=\lim_\frac{\textbf{x}=\textbf{x}_0+s.\textbf{h}}{s\longrightarrow 0} \hspace{1mm} \lim_{t\longrightarrow 0}  \frac{f(\textbf{x}+t\textbf{e}_i)-f(\textbf{x})}{t}$
Then is the following correct?
$\displaystyle l_i= \lim_{t\longrightarrow 0} \frac{f(\textbf{x}_0+t\textbf{h}+t\textbf{e}_i)-f(\textbf{x}_0+t\textbf{h})}{t}$

And now by the mean value theorem:

$\displaystyle l_i=\lim_{t\longrightarrow 0} \frac{df(\textbf{x}_0+t\textbf{h}+st\textbf{e}_i)t\textbf{e}_i}{t}=df(\textbf{x}_0)\textbf{e}_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x}_0)$

Comment: Your question in confused: the relation $l_i = f_i(\mathbf{x})$ is meaningless, since $\mathbf{x}$ is a free variable.

Comment: I've just changed it a bit with a new reasoning. Is it more understandable?

Comment: Partial derivatives are functions of a single variable. You can simply apply the corresponding theorem for functions of a real variable $n$ times.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your last comment... Could please explain yourself in a more detailed way?

Comment: If you can prove the statement in dimension one, then you can prove it in any dimension, since you are working with each partial derivative separately. In one dimension, by the theorem of Lagrange, $$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(c)$$ for some $c \in (x_0,x)$. If $x \to x_0$, then $c \to x_0$, and by assumption $f'(c) \to \ell$. Hence $f'(x_0)$ exists and equals $\ell$.

Comment: Many thanks, Siminore. I think I understand now. =)

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x}_0)= \lim_{t\longrightarrow 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x}_0+t\mathbf{e}_i)-f(\mathbf{x}_0)}{t}=\lim_{t\longrightarrow 0} df(\mathbf{x}_0+t\mathbf{e}_i)\mathbf{e}_i$
$\displaystyle l_i=\lim_{\mathbf{x}\longrightarrow \mathbf{x}_0}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x})=\lim_{t\longrightarrow 0}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x}_0+t\mathbf{e}_i)=\lim_{t\longrightarrow 0}df(\mathbf{x}_0+t\mathbf{e}_i)\mathbf{e}_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\mathbf{x}_0)$

Comment: @Siminore Was this what you meant? I hope so...=)

Comment: Yes, you just choose a direction and apply the MVT along it.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. If you found the answer to your question, might I suggest that you self-answer (and accept) your question. This may help to remove this question from the unanswered queue. If you do, you can post a link to your answer [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers) to draw some attention to it and possibly get some upvotes.

Comment: @gebruiker I don't have the time right now, and I may forget about this... If you write an answer I'll accept it. ;)